# Proving $\arccos{\frac{a+\delta}{c}}\approx \arccos{\frac{a}{c}+\frac{\delta}{c}} $ for small $\delta$

Tags: trigonometry

I have seen several papers that approximate
$$ \arccos({-\frac{a+\delta}{c}})\approx \arccos(-{\frac{a}{c})+\frac{\delta}{b}} $$
where $ b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2} $ provided that $\delta$ is small. Is there any "longer" proof for that? Thank you.
To be exact this is the source of the equation
Doǧançay, K. (2005). Emitter localization using clustering-based bearing association. IEEE Transactions on Aerospace and Electronic Systems, 41(2), 525–536
[image: the mentioned equation]

Comment: It'd be helpful for context if you attached one or more of these papers, so people can give you more specific comments regarding why that substitution was used in that particular scenario.

Comment: If you don't tell us the proof(s) you know, how can we tell what "longer" means?

Comment: $\arccos$ is a _decreasing_ function. So the sign of $\frac{\delta}{c}$ is wrong (as well as its magnitude, as others have pointed out). Are you sure you have the right function here?

Comment: Doǧançay, K. (2005). Emitter localization using clustering-based bearing association. IEEE Transactions on Aerospace and Electronic Systems, 41(2), 525–536. is one of the paper

Comment: Your formula is nothing like the one in your screenshot! Firstly, $\sqrt{||\mathbf{r}_{1i}||^2-g_{1i}^2}$ is not $||\mathbf{r}_{1i}||$; and secondly, $+$ is not $-$.

Comment: I updated the equation where $ b = \sqrt{c^2-a^2}$

Comment: @Semar Thanks very much for the additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit more complex that that. By Taylor, you have
$$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{a+\delta }{c}\right)=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-\frac{\delta }{
   \sqrt{c^2 -a^2}}+O\left(\delta ^2\right)$$

Trying with old pocket calculator for $a=1$, $b=2$, $\delta=\frac 1{10}$, the result is
$$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{20}\right) \sim 0.988432$$ while the above truncated expansion gives
$$\frac{\pi }{3}-\frac{1}{10 \sqrt{3}}\sim 0.989463$$

For sure, if $a \ll c$ your expression is almost OK. Except that, quoting @TonyK, *"the sign is wrong"*.

Comment: "almost OK": no, the sign is wrong too!

Comment: @TonyK. For sure ! I shall edit and quote you ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

For any real map $f(x)$ which has a derivative at $x_0$, you have

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \left(f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) -f^\prime(x_0)h\right) = 0$$

Applying that to $f(x) = \arccos x$ you get

$$ \arccos{\frac{a+\delta}{c}}\approx \arccos{\frac{a}{c}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^2}}\frac{\delta}{c}} $$ as

$$\arccos^\prime(x)= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Which would be a better approximation than the one of your question specially when $a/c$ is close to $\pm 1$.